# angular Api Request with Basic Authorizartion

Tags: angular, get, basic-authentication

How Would I make this Jquery request in **Angular Framework**?? I am very New with angular framework but I am in Love with it. And I love to figure out how to make a HTTP Get using a Basic Authorization header.

```
var settings = {
  "url": "https://sampleapi.com",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "authorization": "Basic QjNYRnZ6S1Jk",
    "content-type": "aplication/json"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

should I build a Service controller or just a regular component.

Comment: if you are so in love with the framework, why dont you start with a basic tutorial that covers HTTP related questions? (there are A LOT of them)

Comment: Or maybe just google around: https://angular.io/guide/http (first result for angular http request)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`RequestOptions`](https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions)** as below

```
const url = `https://sampleapi.com`;
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic QjNYRnZ6S1Jk');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.get(url, options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleErrors);

private extractData(res: Response) {
            const data = res.json();
            return data;
}

private handleErrors(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that could work for you if you are using Angular 4.3 and higher, and want to use the new HttpClient and HttpHeaders.

Here is a service that does the call with basic authorization:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

const url = `https://sampleapi.com`;

@Injectable()
export class BasicService {
  private _headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getWithBasicAuth(): Observable<any> {
    const headers = this._headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic QjNYRnZ6S1Jk');
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(url, { headers : headers });
  }
}
```

Here is a component that would consume the service above.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BasicService } from '../services/basic.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-basic',
  templateUrl: './basic.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./basic.component.css']
})
export class BasicComponent implements OnInit {
  dataFormService: any;

  constructor(private basicService: BasicService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.basicService.getWithBasicAuth().subscribe(data => this.dataFormService = data);
  }
}
```

You may want to change the return type from the service from `any` to something more appropriate.